# Variable name precidence order

Tags: java

I tired to find out the precedence order , Wrote following code which is behaving peculiar . I expected answer black but it gives white .

Can any one helps me understanding this .

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(X.Y.Z); // prints 'White'
    }
}

class X {
    static class Y {
        static String Z = "Black";
    }

    static C Y = new C();
}

class C {
    String Z = "White";
}
```

Comment: The statement `static C Y = new C();` causes the code to print out 'white' instead of 'black' because this overrides the static member Y of class X. Besides of that, this is horrible code. It is very unreadable.

Comment: @SkinnyJ i like how this is exactly the same question just with a class `C` instead of `W` and other strings

Answer (score 3):

You have created a name that [masks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_resolution_%28programming_languages%29#Name_masking) the static class `Y` (of type `C`). To get `black` you'd have to access the class `Y`. You could do that like,

```
System.out.println(new X.Y().Z); //<-- prints black
```

or rename the masking field

```
static C Z = new C(); // <-- from Y.
```